# Avoid DIV inside SPAN - Best Practice

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[DIV](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) is a block level element and must not be nested within a SPAN. But many themes hijack this best practice. What CSS, should be applied in order to bypass these errors?

```
<span class="fields col-lg-6">
    <div class="field">
        <label>Otp<span style="color: red;"> *</span></label>
        @Html.TextDoxFor(m => m.Otp)
    </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Make that span a div and you're good. Otherwise this html code is symantically incorrect. You could use JavaScript to change the spans to divs, but better to do it in the template instead.

Comment: @NathanielFlick changing `span` with `js` is a **Bad** idea! forget it at all

Comment: Yes @pedram please read my entire comment.

Comment: I mean do not recommend it even for a trick, best way that you said: `but better to do it in the template instead`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no CSS to bypass the error caused by the HTML construction. You have to do it manually in the code.**

But in your case it's optional, it's up to you what you want.

**1#** *If you want to avoid the `block` style of the `<div>` you can use this CSS:*

```
span>div{display:inline;}
```

or to apply to all child's inside the `span`

```
span div{display:inline;}
```

**2#** *If you want to avoid the `inline` style of the `<span>` you can use this CSS:*

```
span.fields{display:block;}
```

or to nest, all the child's properly

```
span.fields{display:inline-block;}
```

Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: Maybe it works on `view` but in terms of **SEO** `div is a block level element and must not be nested inside SPAN` and after add display block or inline or anything else, this error will not be fixed, like in w3 validator

Comment: @pedram I completely agree with you bro that's why I first cleared that firstly in my answer. But if he has issues in view he can fix that using the style tweak I gave him. Its optional that all. It's up to him.